# Cant seem to convert timestamp to correct datetime

Tags: timestamp

I am given data with the following timestamp

a) -504701880
b) -441888960
c) -661690320

d) 63378180

Actual date

a)04/02/1985

b)01/04/1987

c)14/08/1980

d)05/03/2003

I can't seem to find what this type of timestamp and correct way to convert them!?!?!

Thanks in advance

Note: The database is provided from Xcode project and I'm loading it into a Android project

Comment: Which language are you working with?

Comment: Are there *any* more context information available here, or will we have to do wild guesses?